# How to add a linebreak into the content of the ::before pseudo element using attr()

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I wan't to add a linebreak in the content of a `::before` using a dataset.

###### Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<span id="timer-container" title="11" data-average="0:00 \a 0:00">
    <p id="hours">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">:</p>
    <p id="minutes">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">:</p>
    <p id="seconds">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">.</p>
    <p id="milliseconds">00</p>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#timer-container::before {
    content: attr(data-average);
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\A` use the numeric entity reference `&#xA;`

```css
#timer-container::before {
    content: attr(data-average);
    white-space: pre-line;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<span id="timer-container" title="11" data-average="0:00 &#xA; 0:00">
    <p id="hours">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">:</p>
    <p id="minutes">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">:</p>
    <p id="seconds">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">.</p>
    <p id="milliseconds">00</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why this works when using \A does not but put it here in case it helps.

In the text editor (notepad++) I just typed in a newline instead of the \a and it works:

```html
<span id="timer-container" title="11" data-average="0:00
0:00">
    <p id="hours">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">:</p>
    <p id="minutes">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">:</p>
    <p id="seconds">0</p>
    <p class="seperation">.</p>
    <p id="milliseconds">00</p>
</span>
<style>
  #timer-container::before {
    content: attr(data-average);
    white-space: pre;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
</style>
```